# Retrieve specific preceding sibling nodes attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

Is there an XPath way of recovering directly one specific attribute of preceding sibling nodes of an XML node using an XPath query?

In the following example, I would like to retrieve the values of the `alt` attribute of each `img` nodes that precede the `div` element marked with the `id=marker`.

```
<content>
  <img alt="1" src="file.gif" />
  <img alt="2" src="file.gif" />
  <img alt="3" src="file.gif" />
  <img alt="4" src="file.gif" />
  <div id='marker'></div>
</content>
```

For this example, I want to retrieve the values `1 2 3 4`.
I use the following XPath query

```
//div[@id='marker']/preceding-sibling::img
```

in order to retrieve the node list I want

```
<img alt="1" src="file.gif"/>
<img alt="2" src="file.gif"/>
<img alt="3" src="file.gif"/>
<img alt="4" src="file.gif"/>
```

As it is a node list I can then iterate on the nodes to retrieve the attribute value I am looking for, but is there an XPath way of doing it? 
I would have expected to be able to write something like:

```
//div[@id='marker']/preceding-sibling::img@alt
or //div[@id='marker']/preceding-sibling@alt::img
```

but I don't even know if it is possible once you have used an `XPath Axe` like preceding-sibling.

Comment: @skaffman: may I ask you why you removed my `sibling` tag please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use**:

**`//div[@id='marker']/preceding-sibling::img/@alt`**

This selects all attributes (attribute nodes) names `alt` of all `img` elements that are preceding siblings of some `div` element (anywhere in the XML document) whose `id` attribute has the value `'marker'`.

**In XPath 2.0 you can even obtain a sequence of strings that are the values of these `alt` attributes**:

**`//div[@id='marker']/preceding-sibling::img/@alt/string()`**